# Installing latest ubuntu on thinkpad?

Tags: system-installation

I've decided to install Ubuntu on my Lenovo Thinkpad T430, and after looking some things up, I found that a version of 12.04 is compatible with it, but my question is, can I install the latest version of Ubuntu on the laptop just fine, or would that not work? It seems to me like there shouldn't be any problems except maybe that the fingerprint scanner wouldn't work. I haven't found any newer version of Ubuntu that's actually "made to work" with this particular laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

12.04 is an excellent way to get started. It has been around so it is working well and it still has over 2 years of life (updates).

Make a usb drive it's faster than a disk. Get the iso from here http://releases.ubuntu.com/

The operating system you have on the laptop now might give you trouble when trying to install Ubuntu. If you have Win7 great no problems, you can dual boot (have both) or erase Win7 and just have Ubuntu. If you have Windows 8 then you might have trouble. Here is a guide from Ubuntu https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

I have found the easiest way is to completely erase the drive and partitions. Then it was easy to install Ubuntu, and fun to delete windows.